# org-mode show image inline from remote server

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tramp

I would like to execute a dot command from remote server, then show the output png image in my org-mode.

```
* remote dot demo

#+NAME:dotsrc
#+begin_example
digraph RecordShapedNodes {
   rankdir="LR";
   graph [ pad=0.02, nodesep=0, ranksep=1 fontname=Courier,fontsize=8,labeljust=l,nojustify=true ];
   node [ shape=box margin="0.01,0.01" width=0 height=0 fontsize=25 ]
   A [ shape=record label="<a0>AAA|<a1>B" ]
   B [ shape=record label="<b0>C\l|<b1>CCCCCC" rankjustify=x ]
   C [ shape=record label="<c0>D\l|<c1>DDDDDDDD" rankjustify=l ]
   A:a0 -> B:b1
   A:a1 -> C:c0
}
#+end_example

#+begin_src bash :dir /ssh:test1@myserver:/home/user1 :results output :session :var dotsrc=dotsrc
#echo $dotsrc
echo $dotsrc >input.dot
dot -Tpng -Nshape=box -o output.png input.dot
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

After running the code block with `C-c C-c`, I expected the `output.png` to show in the results block, but it is produced on the remote server. How can I show it locally in my Emacs?

Comment: So what happened? Is there an error? What does the error say?

Comment: no any error, but the output.png is in remote server, i would like to show it on my emacs locally.

Comment: I edited your question with the additional information. Please check it for accuracy (and for future reference, please make sure to include all relevant information *in the question* - not in comments).

Comment: I believe the output of the src block is the output of the bash script, which is the status of the last command, or its output (there isn't any) rather than the file that the dot command produces.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? It seems orgmode does not support ssh remote images, but I can't find confirmation in the docs.